# Trying to find the right way to "flick" a widget off screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Very new to Flutter development. I am wanting to make a game where, in a nutshell, you "flick" things off screen. So an object will show up on the screen and you need to flick it off. I keep using that term because you don't need to drag it all the way off, you just need to literally flick it off. Think of the screen in either iOS or Android where you flick apps to close them. I'm trying to basically have that type of mechanics.

I just don't know how best to do that. I can show my object and can drag it around (limiting it to just vertical dragging) and I can detect when it has upwards velocity on the drag, but I don't know how to get it to keep transitioning upwards and off the screen when the user lets go of it.

I will have a collection of these objects that keep coming on the screen and will need to be flicked away. Any help with transitioning it out of the screen would be of great help.

Here's my draggable object so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FlickableObject extends StatelessWidget {
  const FlickableObject({super.key});

  final double _x = 100.0;
  final double _y = 100.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final flickableWidget = Image.asset(
      'assets/images/flickable_object.png',
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
    );

    return Positioned(
      left: _x,
      top: _y,
      child:  Draggable(
          feedback: Transform.rotate(
            angle: 0.1,
            child: flickableWidget,
          ),
          childWhenDragging: Opacity(
            opacity: 0.0,
            child: flickableWidget,
          ),
          axis: Axis.vertical,
          onDragEnd: (drag) {
            if (drag.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy < 0) {
              print("Successful flick!");
            }
          },
          child: flickableWidget,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Dismissible, perhaps?